# Word for institutions that lost their purpose but continue to exist anyways

Tags: word-request, terminology

I’m looking for a specific word for institutions that lost their original purpose but for some reason or another (lack of accounability, bad management) continue to exist anyways and do what they have been doing all along.

By „institutions“ I mean subdivisions of some larger organization.

I remember the term having its own Wikipedia page but I can’t find it anymore. I also think it was more of a tongue-in-cheek term rather than a technical term but I might be wrong on that one.

Comment: See [***skeuomorph***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph) - typical examples being pictures of antiquated box cameras and old-style telephone handsets used as icons on modern computers and smartphones (the *image* survives long after the *actual* thing is no longer relevant to modern life). Or you could say some "outdated" institution is ***vestigial*** (literally, *biologically* superseded).

Comment: Zombie organizations is a term I have heard.